# Disable Working in Background Cursor from system ( not application)

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, cursor

I have a application that works at background , and when my application start the appstarting
cursor blink once ( everytime ), and it is pretty annoying to see how cursor icon switches many times from normal arrow to appstart or “Working in background” hourglass with arrow.

How can I make the appstrating cursor disable, run my application and then enable it back, so the user doesn't feel any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor does not change by default so I think this must be something in your code doign this. To set the cursor back to 'normal' use the following:

`Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default`

or just find where you are setting it in the first place and remove the line

Comment: i have mentioned cursor working in background for system , not for my application , anyways thanks for replying